# Inconsistency between GRU and RNN implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement some custom GRU cells using Tensorflow. I need to stack those cells, and I wanted to inherit from [`tensorflow.keras.layers.GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU). However, when looking at the source code, I noticed that you can only pass a `units` argument to the `__init__` of `GRU`, while [`RNN`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN) has an argument that is a list of `RNNcell`, and leverages it to stack those cells calling `StackedRNNCells`. Meanwhile, `GRU` only create one `GRUCell`.

For the paper I'm trying to implement, I actually need to stack `GRUCell`. Why are the implementation of `RNN` and `GRU` different?

Comment: [`GRUCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/GRUCell) inherits from [`LayerRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LayerRNNCell) which inherits from [`RNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/RNNCell). Can you just pass `GRUCell` objects into an `RNN` framework to stack them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching for the documentation for these classes to add links, I noticed something that may be tripping you up: there are (currently, just before the official TF 2.0 release) *two* `GRUCell` implementations in TensorFlow! There is a [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/GRUCell) and a [`tf.keras.layers.GRUCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRUCell). It looks like the one from `tf.nn.rnn_cell` is deprecated, and the Keras one is the one you should use.

From what I can tell, the `GRUCell` has the same `__call__()` method signature as [`tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell) and [`tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNNCell), and they all inherit from `Layer`. The [`RNN`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN) documentation gives some requirements on what the `__call__()` method of the objects you pass to its `cell` argument must do, but my guess is that all three of these should meet those requirements. You should be able to just use the same `RNN` framework and pass it a list of `GRUCell` objects instead of `LSTMCell` or `SimpleRNNCell`.

I can't test this right now, so I'm not sure if you pass a list of `GRUCell` objects or just [`GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) objects into `RNN`, but I think one of those should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked indeed. However, I still think that this difference between ``GRU`` and ``RNN`` is strange. Maybe ``GRU`` implementation is only for backwards compatibility, and stacking any kind of recurrent cells should be done with ``RNN``.

Answer (score 0):

train_graph = tf.Graph()
with train_graph.as_default():

```
# Initialize input placeholders
input_text = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='input')
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='targets')
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate')

# Calculate text attributes
vocab_size = len(int_to_vocab)
input_text_shape = tf.shape(input_text)

# Build the RNN cell
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=rnn_size)
drop_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop_cell] * num_layers)

# Set the initial state
initial_state = cell.zero_state(input_text_shape[0], tf.float32)
initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, name='initial_state')

# Create word embedding as input to RNN
embed = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(input_text, vocab_size, embed_dim)

# Build RNN
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, dtype=tf.float32)
final_state = tf.identity(final_state, name='final_state')

# Take RNN output and make logits
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs, vocab_size, activation_fn=None)

# Calculate the probability of generating each word
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='probs')

# Define loss function
cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(
    logits,
    targets,
    tf.ones([input_text_shape[0], input_text_shape[1]])
)
```

# Learning rate optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

```
# Gradient clipping to avoid exploding gradients
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, however I was not using this interface, but the new ones from ``tf.keras.layers``. As Engineero suggested, just passing ``GRUCell``s to ``RNN`` worked.